# What fields determine what is displayed in Open Activities vs. Activity History

Tags: tasks, activities, activityhistory

What determines which tasks go into the boxes Open Activities and Activity history, respectively?
I tried the fields Status, IsArchived, IsClosed, but none of them relate the image I see in my single Account page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Task` records, the differentiation is based on `Status`. You can query for all closed values as follows:

```
Set<String> closedStatuses = new Set<String>();
for(TaskStatus status: [SELECT MasterLabel FROM TaskStatus WHERE IsClosed = true])
    closedStatuses.add(status.MasterLabel);
```

For `Event` records, the differentiation is based solely on the `StartDateTime` field. If it is in the past, it is history. If it is in the future, it is open.

Comment: Event.EndDateTime >= TODAY() then it is open, otherwise it's history (no pun intended).

Comment: @sfdcfox Not when I tested it to confirm. I did `StartDateTime` yesterday and `EndDateTime` tomorrow and it went into `Activity History`.

Comment: That's curious. Maybe I just remembered it wrong. It wouldn't be the first time.