# Trigger : How to track once an event moves from "Open Activities" to "Activity History"?

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks, event, activities

I have an event record E on my Opportunity O.

E starts at 07/03/2018 11:00 AM and ends at 07/03/2018 11:30 AM.

Before the event E appears in "Open Activities" and once the event start time is past it appears in "Activity History".

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to track the transition ?.

I need to perform few operations once an event moves from "Open Activities" to "Activity History" but since the transition is not DML based (*i could be wrong*) I am not sure how I can write a trigger for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See also: [What fields determine what is displayed in Open Activities vs. Activity History](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/142924/2995)

For `Task` records, you can write a trigger that compares the old and new value of `IsClosed`.

```
trigger Task on Task (before update)
{
    // handler, service, etc omitted for brevity
    for (Task record : trigger.new)
    {
        Task oldRecord = trigger.oldMap.get(record.Id);
        if (record.IsClosed && !oldRecord.IsClosed)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

For `Event` records, you will need a scheduled job in which you look for records whose `StartDateTime` is less than `Datetime.now()`, but also greater than the last time the job was run. There are a variety of ways to do that. The simplest may be to run the job daily and look for records which started yesterday, but you could also use a `Hierarchy Custom Setting` or query for the last time the job was run. I'm sure there are other approaches which would work as well. If you run it daily, that would look something like:

```
public class MyEventJob implements Scheduleable
{
    public void execute(ScheduleableContext context)
    {
        for (Event record : [
            SELECT Id FROM Event
            WHERE StartDateTime = YESTERDAY
        ]){
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```